# Is there a difference between torch.IntTensor and torch.Tensor

Tags: python, types, tensor, torch

When using PyTorch tensors, is there a point to initialize my data like so:

```
X_tensor: torch.IntTensor = torch.IntTensor(X)
Y_tensor: torch.IntTensor = torch.IntTensor(Y)
```

Or should I just do the 'standard':

```
X_tensor: torch.Tensor = torch.Tensor(X)
Y_tensor: torch.Tensor = torch.Tensor(Y)
```

even though I know `X: list[list[int]` and `Y: list[list[int]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `torch.IntTensor()` or `torch.Tensor()` you end up with

- either a tensor that  can hold signed integer values and requires 32-bits per value
- or a tensor that can hold 32-bit floating-point numbers as `torch.Tensor` returns (respect. is alias for) a `torch.FloatTensor`.

Using `torch.tensor(X)` (with only integers in `X`) on the other hand will lead  64-bit integer tensor by default as `torch.tensor()` infers the data type automatically.

```py
import torch

X = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]

x1 = torch.IntTensor(X)
x2 = torch.Tensor(X)
x3 = torch.tensor(X)

print(x1.dtype)  # torch.int32
print(x2.dtype)  # torch.float32
print(x3.dtype)  # torch.int64
```

What you need, depends on what you want to do with the data.
For computations in neural networks usually tensors with 32-bit floating-point precision are used.

That said, pytorch automatically converts data to the larger type, if data types are mixed within calculations.
So this works:

```py
c = 3.1
print(x1*c, (x1*c).dtype)  # tensor([[ 3.1000,  6.2000], [ 9.3000, 12.4000]]) torch.float32
print(x2*c, (x2*c).dtype)  # tensor([[ 3.1000,  6.2000], [ 9.3000, 12.4000]]) torch.float32
```

But this also works (though the result is "wrong" (rounded) - so better directly start with the precision required).

```py
data_float32 = torch.tensor([0.1, 0.2, 0.3])
data_int16 = data_float32.to(torch.short)
data_squared = data_float32 * data_int16
print(data_squared, data_squared.dtype)  # tensor([0., 0., 0.]) torch.float32
```

Comment: Just a little question, `torch.short` encodes it on 16 bits but doesn’t necessarily mean we’ll have an integer?

Comment: After reading the documentation (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.short.html), it seems that it's the case. However, is it not possible to encode a float with precision 16?

Comment: float with precision 16 would be `torch.half` (half precision floating point). Conversion could be done like this (using the example above) : `data_float32.to(torch.half)`. Or for initialising a float16 tensor directly: `torch.tensor(X, dtype=torch.float16)`

Comment: Just needed a conversion to an integer tensor for the example above, to make the point that automatic conversion might lead to errors. Sorry, if it caused confusion.

Comment: Oh ok, it's very clear now!

Answer (score 2):

- `torch.IntTensor(X)`: returns tensor of `int32`
- `torch.Tensor(X)`: returns tensor of `float32`

What to use depends on what your forward function is expecting specially your loss function. Most loss functions operate on float tensors.